# CS-Cart Multi-Vendor - Vendor order notifications

Tags: php, templates, e-commerce, cs-cart

When an order status gets updated, CS-Cart sends out two emails.  One to the customer `fn.cart.php:6102` and one to the vendor `fn.cart.php:6123`.

Currently to override the template I copied templates from
`design/backend/mail/templates/order/order_notification.tpl`
and
`design/backend/mail/templates/order/order_notification_subl.tpl`,

to my theme
`design/themes/mytheme/mail/templates/order/order_notification.tpl` and
`design/themes/mytheme/mail/templates/order/order_notification_subl.tpl`.

**My custom template only gets used on the client notification email, but I need it on the vendor notification too.  Is there a way to make this happen?**

---

I tried digging in a bit deeper, but got no-where.

It seems that when the vendor email gets sent, they pass a param `'A'` to the `Mailer::sendMail($params, 'A')` function call.

Then when the template path is built in the `fn_get_theme_path()` function (`fn.common.php:108`), the design directory gets set to the `backend/` folder instead of the `themes/` if the `$area` is `A`.

Am I overlooking something or is my only option to hack the core?

Answer (score 1):

When the area is "A" or "V" (admin, respectively "vendor"), CS-Cart uses the templates from `backend`.
When the area is "C" (customer), it will use your theme, ie. `mytheme` templates.

And both themes have a copy (slightly different if I remember correctly) of the order_notification.tpl and order_notification_subj.tpl templates.
So you have the override both of them.

You will not be able to override a backend template from your frontend template, unless you're ready for some over complicated workarounds.

It would be a better idea to override them from a custom add-on, and maybe use `send_mail_pre` in Mailer.php hook to override the template paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have a go at the hook mentioned :)